# How to get $post object available inside functions.php to localize script?

Tags: custom-post-types, themes, wp-localize-script

I have a problem with a wp_localize_script in my functions.php file. 
I am trying to get a script localized for a custom post type ("gallery"), however, the error emerges that I am trying to access a property of non-object referring to $post. I assume that $post variable is undefined at this moment, but can't figure out what should I do to fix this. Should I use another hook action etc? If yes, what? 
 So, basically, I have two questions  - what should I do to fix this code and the second (more general one) - is there any good practice for using wp_localize_script (where should it be placed etc.)?

```
    function profolio_localize_script () {
        global $post; 
        if ($post->post_type==="my-gallery") {
            $layoutType=get_post_meta($post->ID,"gallery_layout",true);
            $data_array=array("layoutMode"=>$layoutType);
            wp_enqueue_script("custom", get_template_directory_uri () . "/js/custom.js", array("jquery","imagesLoaded","isotope"));
            wp_localize_script("custom","myGallery",$data_array); 
        }
    }
add_action("wp",  "profolio_localize_script");
```

Comment: Is this information not suffice to advise me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `wp` action hook fires pretty early, before the `$post` object is set. I would suggest using the appropriate hook `wp_enqueue_scripts` instead, and amending your code to:

```
function profolio_localize_script () {
    if ( is_singular( 'my-gallery' ) ) {
        $layoutType = get_post_meta( get_queried_object_id(), 'gallery_layout', true );
        // Rest of code 
    }
}
```